# Background does not fill the entire height of div as it's resized

Tags: html, css

In the example below the background color of the text does not appear when the text has two lines:

[image]

```css
#Group_82 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 544px;
 height: 66px;
 left: 4px;
 top: 10px;
 overflow: visible;
 animation: resize 2500ms linear 0s infinite;
}

.Rectangle_445 {
 position: absolute;
 overflow: visible;
 width: 100%;
 height: 66px;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
}

#text1 {
 position: absolute;
 left: 20px;
 right: 20px;
 top: 10px;
 overflow: visible;
 height: 14px;
 text-align: left;
 font-family: Helvetica Neue;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: rgba(112,112,112,1);
 background-color: lightblue;
}

@keyframes resize {
  0% {
    width: 92%;
  }
  37.5% {
    width: 92%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 45%;
  }
  87.5% {
    width: 45%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 92%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Group_82" class="resize92to50">
  <svg class="Rectangle_445">
    <rect fill="rgba(234,234,234,1)" stroke="rgba(183,183,183,1)" stroke-width="1px" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-miterlimit="4" shape-rendering="auto" id="Rectangle_445" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="66">
    </rect>
  </svg>
  <div id="text1">
    <span>The text is anchored to the left and right edge of the group</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `height: 14px;`

Comment: @MrLister Missed that. Thanks

Comment: Does that solve the problem? Then we can close this as too localized.

Comment: @MrLister It looks like there's another solution. Your and and Jenish answer is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have solution your problem.

```
<div id="Group_82" class="resize92to50">
    <svg class="Rectangle_445">
        <rect fill="rgba(234,234,234,1)" stroke="rgba(183,183,183,1)" stroke-width="1px" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-miterlimit="4" shape-rendering="auto" id="Rectangle_445" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="66">
        </rect>
    </svg>
    <div id="text1">
        <span style="background-color: lightblue;">The text is anchored to the left and right edge of the group</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add background color in  (tag). Do not set background color of "text1" div...